# Move folder using windows copier in VB6

Tags: windows, winapi, vb6

How can I move a folder (with sub-folders in it) using windows file copier dialog box in VB6. I mean it should move the folder using windows file copier .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function to call is `SHFileOperation`. Have a look [here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/shell/shfileopadv.htm) for some example VB6 code.

Comment: `SHFileOperation()` is deprecated and replaced by the [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx) interface in Vista and later.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, Win 7 still have `SHFileOperation`. It is working in Win 7. I guess it should also work in Win 8.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I doubt anyone still programming in VB6 is that concerned about what's deprecated and what's not :)

Comment: @VarunAgw: Microsoft does not remove deprecated APIs, for backwards compatibility. So they still "work", but that does not mean they are still "supported". The `IFileOperation` doc specifically says: "This interface replaces the SHFileOperation function.".

Comment: @JonathanPotter: true. On the other hand, being a COM object, VB code can easily make use of `IFileOperation` if desired and when available. And one nice thing about using it is that under UAC, it can be used in an elevated state from a non-elevated process via the COM Elevation Moniker.